# Vieta's formulas for quadratic equation problem

Tags: quadratics

I'm using one hack, which I never though of why it works. But now I'm curious why it's works and how I can prove it.
Here's the deal: we have quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, to find roots I just multiply $c$ by $a$ and solving $y^2 + by + ca = 0$, and then I divide roots by $a$.

For example:
$$-6x^2+7x+5=0$$
I solve
$$
y^2 + 7y -30 = 0\\
y_1=-10\\
y_2=3
$$
And then divide the roots:
$$
x_1=\frac{-10}{-6}=\frac{5}{3}\\
x_2=\frac{3}{-6}=-\frac{1}{2}
$$
Which gives me a correct answer. But I want to know why it's so. For now what I figured out is only that:
$$
\text{for } a\neq 0 \text{ :}\\
ax^2 + bx + c = 0 \Leftrightarrow x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x + \frac{c}{a} = 0\\
x_1 + x_2 = -\frac{b}{a} \Leftrightarrow a(x_1 + x_2) = -b\\
x_1 \cdot x_2 = \frac{c}{a} \Leftrightarrow a(x_1 \cdot x_2) = c\\
$$
$$
y^2 + by + ca = 0\\
y_1 + y_1 = -b\\
y_1 \cdot y_2 = ca \Leftrightarrow c = \frac{y_1 \cdot y_2}{a}\\
$$
$$
a(x_1 + x_2) = y_1 + y_1 \Leftrightarrow x_1 + x_2 = \frac{y_1}{a} + \frac{y_2}{a}\\
a(x_1 \cdot x_2) = \frac{y_1 \cdot y_2}{a} \Leftrightarrow x_1 \cdot x_2 = \frac{y_1}{a} \cdot \frac{y_2}{a}\\
$$
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the original equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ then multiply by $a$ to obtain $$a^2x^2+abx+ac=0$$Now set $y=ax$ so that $$y^2+by+ac=0$$ and you are done.

Comment: Damn, that was so easy. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Zekfad That trick of changing the variable can often be used with Vieta to shorten calculations (cubics and quartics are problems often set in this kind of area)

Answer (score 1):

By the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) the roots of $aX^2+bX+c$ are $x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.

The roots of $Y^2+bY+ca$ are $y=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ca}}{2}$...

We see that $x=\frac1a y$ ...